# Running a script from ssh, logging out and continuing the script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, script

The overall question here is - how do I automate sshing into a machine, running a script, and exiting without killing the script? I know that this has been answered several times, but I'm not having luck with the solutions I've found.

The details:

I have code running on several machines that I ssh into.

Right now, I'm doing the following in a terminal:

```
ssh machine1@host (log in automatically with key)
screen -S screen_name
./script.sh
<keystroke C-a-d>
exit
```

Time consuming, and more importantly, prone to errors (open a screen and exit it without running the script, etc.).

I'd like to automate this. My first thought was to try to replicate this exactly. I tried xdotool to send the keystrokes, but my environment is command line only, and it seems like the wrong tool for the job. Similarly expect looks like it could be used instead of xdotool, but again, probably the wrong way to do it.

I also tried using nohup instead of screen, by doing 
   nohup ./script.sh &

but when I log out of the ssh session and come back, it looks like the script stopped running when I logged out. As far as I can tell, nohup is the right way to do it.

Comment: Why do you think the background `nohup` stopped running?  @l0b0's  answer is proposing exactly what you're doing, just removing the step of manually logging in.  There's no reason a command that's backgrounded via nohup should stop running, unless it actually finished . . .

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why now. I'll update the question when I do, but right now I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr:

```
$ ssh host 'nohup your-command &' &
```

Here's an example:

```
$ ssh localhost 'nohup sleep 10 &' &
[1] 12345
$ sleep 5 && ps x | grep '[s]leep 10'
24044 pts/0    S      0:00 ssh localhost nohup sleep 10 &
24054 ?        S      0:00 sleep 10
```

This starts an SSH connection, runs `sleep 10` in the background on the target host (which happens to be your local host), and checks the process list (`ps`) to verify that it's still running **after** `ssh` finishes.